# Android App 30 day expiry

Tags: applications

I downloaded an app that had a 30 day trial about 5 months ago and never used it, so uninstalled it. I have downloaded it again and it wont register as it 'sees' it has being installed on the device before...... any thoughts on where the App is getting its information?

Comment: Uninstallations sometime leave remnant folders on the SD card or internal storage.

Comment: This may depend on how the app implements it, so to avoid guessing, could you mention the app name? Have you opened it at least once before uninstalled it?

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! Opinion-based questions are discouraged on Stack Exchange sites and may be closed. To avoid your question being closed, you should edit it and add information to aid finding factual answers (as @Andrew said).

Answer (score 0):

Since you have already downloaded the app once it will keep track of your 'Device ID' or even the 'google account' that you used to download the app.